# System.Net.WebException: Sharing violation on path

Tags: c#, imagen, pdf, excepciones, xamarin.android

Estoy creando una app en Xamarin para android que al finalizar su tarea, crea un PDF con iTextSharp.

Tengo un problema ya que esta app tiene un SignaturePad, captura la firma y la inserta en el PDF.
Cuando captura la firma por primera vez no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando lo hago por 2da vez salta la siguiente excepcion:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.Net.WebException: Sharing violation on path /mnt/sdcard/ProyectoTest/Firma.jpg

No tengo ni idea a que se debe, ya que la imágen de la firma se está guardando sin problemas y en el PDF antes de insertar la firma pongo 2 o 3 imágenes más y en ninguna de ellas tengo problema.

Dejo aquí la parte donde ingreso la imágen para que puedan revisarlo, si necesitan más partes del código me avisan en los comentarios:

```
string RutaFirma = "/mnt/sdcard/ProyectoTest/Firma.jpg";
Image FirmaPaciente = Image.GetInstance(RutaFirma);
FirmaPaciente.ScalePercent(20);
FirmaPaciente.SetAbsolutePosition(380, 150);
document.Add(FirmaPaciente);
```

Comment: Parece que el fichero queda en uso después del primer uso. ¿Haces alguna cosa más con la imagen a parte de esto?

Comment: El proceso es el siguiente: Desde la clase principal llama al SignaturePad, hace la firma y genera el PDF... cuando termina de generar el PDF vuelve a la clase principal y se vuelve a repetir el proceso

Comment: Ya encontré el error. Era algo tan basico que hasta me da vergüenza decirlo... faltaba el close() del SignaturePad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de lidiar bastante con el asunto encontré el problema:
El problema fue algo muy básico de IO.

Este es el método donde se genera la firma:

```
private async void BtnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var directory = new Java.IO.File("/mnt/sdcard", "ProyectoTest").ToString();

    if (!Directory.Exists(directory)){
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }

    path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "Firma.jpg");

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)){
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
    }

    Stream bitmap = await FirmaPaciente.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png, Color.Black, Color.White, 1f);
    FileStream dest = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path);
    await bitmap.CopyToAsync(dest);
    FinishAfterTransition();
}
```

Faltaba el `dest.Close();` antes del `FinishAfterTransition();`!!!